# Python parsing string,lists

Tags: json, python-3.x, list, parsing, tuples

I am currently struggling to parse the following string - the response from API request - 
https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/deep/book?symbols=goog

the output from this API is

> {"GOOG":{"bids":[{"price":1030.79,"size":100,"timestamp":1541428203560},{"price":1003.79,"size":200,"timestamp":1541429104723}],"asks":[{"price":1040.62,"size":100,"timestamp":1541429609821},{"price":1084.79,"size":100,"timestamp":1541428203541},{"price":1111.79,"size":200,"timestamp":1541428981007}]}}

Looking to get the `price` value and `size` value from the output both bids and asks. To save it in data frames or another workable format.

Thank you for your help!

---

I was able to get the first line of each by formatting it into fdataframe and indexing, like

```
a = pd.read_json(url).dropna()
r = pd.DataFrame(a)
print(r.iloc[0][0][0])
```

Response

```
{'timestamp': 1541428203541, 'price': 1084.79, 'size': 100}
```

but I still need to parse it somehow to get `price` and `size` values...

Comment: If you could provide a little context to what you have tried so far or language you would like to use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that this is JSON; use [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) to convert it into a nested dictionary.

```
>>> line = '{"GOOG":{"bids":[{"price":1070.92,"size":100,"timestamp":1541089522066}],"asks":[]}}'
>>> d = json.loads(line)
>>> d["GOOG"]["bids"][0]["price"]
1070.92
>>> d["GOOG"]["bids"][0]["size"]
100
```

---

From comments:

> ```
> url = "api.iextrading.com/1.0/deep/book?symbols=goog"
> d = json.loads(url)`
> ```

Well, the problem is that you are trying to parse *the URL itself* as a JSON string. This is not what [`json.loads`](https://docs.python.org/3/library/json.html#json.loads) does. Instead, you have to read the content from that URL first, e.g. using [`urllib`](https://docs.python.org/3.5/library/urllib.html), or just use `pandas.read_json` as you already did in the other code in your question:

```
>>> d = pd.read_json(url).to_dict()
>>> d["GOOG"]["bids"][0]["price"]
1037.23
```

Comment: It is showing the error, once I attempted to do this.    File "pandas\_libs\hashtable_class_helper.pxi", line 1500, in pandas._libs.hashtable.PyObjectHashTable.get_item
KeyError: 1

Comment: Not sure where keyerror 1 came from, but know I'm getting the following error - Traceback (most recent call last):

  File "C:\Users\Alexander\lib\json\decoder.py", line 357, in raw_decode
    raise JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value) from None
json.decoder.JSONDecodeError: Expecting value: line 1 column 1 (char 0)

Comment: Thank you for your help! Your understanding of the question is correct. I have also edited the question, hopefully, it is better now. Once I tried to run your code - d = json.loads(line), I am getting the error - JSONDecodeError("Expecting value", s, err.value)

Comment: ` ->(a)' just referral, I removed it as it confusing. Link output is different time to time, as it is dynamic. so I posted the response I got at this time this morning, not it's different. But the structure is the same and I believe the appropriate code shoudl work fine, regardless of number of values in output.

Comment: I have nothing to hide, the code is all here, I am running the following   -- import json

url = "https://api.iextrading.com/1.0/deep/book?symbols=goog"

d = json.loads(url)
d["GOOG"]["bids"][0]["price"]

Comment: @AlexZ See, that's the kind of information that I'd needed: The code that produces the error. Now the problem is clear: You are trying to parse a URL as JSON. See my edit.

Comment: Thank you so much, it actually works just perfect! I have never dealt with dictionaries before, but it is exactly what I need. Thank you!